# How to reduce the size of the Wikipedia dump by Okawix?

Tags: xml, mediawiki, wikipedia

Okawix has an app for Android. I have a 12 GB text-only Wikipedia dump, but it's too big to fit on SD card.

Is there any way to create a new dump from this Okawix dump, selecting only computer or IT-related articles only? (I don't want other articles)

Answer (score 1):

Use [Kiwix](http://kiwix.org/) instead: it's completely free software, uses ZIM which has a better compression and has some smaller files with Wikimedia projects (e.g. without images if you need to strip them down a lot).